# Manually/locally installed python packages dont show up in visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, installation, import, package

So I manually installed a locally downloaded python package by going into the folder directory and using the cmd command:

`python setup.py install`

After that it just installed itself normally. Using the python function `help("modules")` in cmd also confirmed that it was installed correctly as I can see the name being given out. The two modules are called `binance_d` and  `binance_f`

```
C:\Users\Hungti>python
Python 3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  6 2021, 13:40:21) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help("modules")

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

  File "C:\Users\Hungti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\autobahn\xbr\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from mnemonic import Mnemonic
No module named 'mnemonic'C:\Users\Hungti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
  warnings.warn(
OpenSSL             antigravity         gettext             requests_toolbelt
__future__          apprise             glob                rlcompleter
_abc                apscheduler         graphlib            runpy
_aix_support        argparse            greenlet            sched
_ast                array               gunicorn            schedule
_asyncio            ast                 gzip                secrets
_bisect             asynchat            hashlib             select
_blake2             asyncio             heapq               selectors
_bootlocale         asyncore            hmac                service_identity
_bootsubprocess     atexit              html                setuptools
_bz2                attr                http                shelve
_cffi_backend       audioop             hyperlink           shlex
_codecs             autobahn            idlelib             shutil
_codecs_cn          automat             idna                signal
_codecs_hk          base64              imaplib             site
_codecs_iso2022     bdb                 imghdr              six
_codecs_jp          bidict              imp                 smtpd
_codecs_kr          binance             importlib           smtplib
_codecs_tw          binance_d           incremental         sndhdr
_collections        binance_f           ingenico            socket
_collections_abc    binascii            inspect             socketio
_compat_pickle      binhex              io                  socketserver
_compression        bisect              ipaddress           sqlalchemy
_contextvars        builtins            itertools           sqlite3
_csv                bz2                 itsdangerous        sqlitedict
_ctypes             cProfile            jinja2              sre_compile
_ctypes_test        cachetools          json                sre_constants
_datetime           calendar            keyword             sre_parse
_decimal            certifi             lib2to3             ssl
_elementtree        cffi                linecache           stat
_functools          cgi                 locale              statistics
_hashlib            cgitb               logging             string
_heapq              chardet             lzma                stringprep
_imp                chunk               mailbox             struct
_io                 click               mailcap             subprocess
_json               cmath               markdown            sunau
_locale             cmd                 markupsafe          symbol
_lsprof             code                marshal             symtable
_lzma               codecs              math                sys
_markupbase         codeop              mimetypes           sysconfig
_md5                collections         mmap                tabnanny
_msi                colorsys            modulefinder        tarfile
_multibytecodec     compileall          msilib              telnetlib
_multiprocessing    concurrent          msvcrt              tempfile
_opcode             configparser        multiprocessing     test
_operator           constantly          netrc               textwrap
_osx_support        contextlib          nntplib             this
_overlapped         contextvars         nt                  threading
_peg_parser         copy                ntpath              time
_pickle             copyreg             nturl2path          timeit
_py_abc             crypt               numbers             tkinter
_pydecimal          cryptography        numpy               token
_pyio               csv                 oauthlib            tokenize
_queue              ctypes              opcode              trace
_random             curses              operator            traceback
_sha1               dataclasses         optparse            tracemalloc
_sha256             dateparser          os                  tty
_sha3               dateparser_data     parser              turtle
_sha512             dateparser_scripts  pathlib             turtledemo
_signal             datetime            pdb                 twisted
_sitebuiltins       dateutil            pickle              txaio
_socket             dbm                 pickletools         types
_sqlite3            decimal             pip                 typing
_sre                difflib             pipes               tzlocal
_ssl                dis                 pkg_resources       ujson
_stat               distutils           pkgutil             unicodedata
_statistics         dns                 platform            unittest
_string             doctest             plistlib            urllib
_strptime           easy_install        poplib              urllib3
_struct             email               posixpath           uu
_symtable           encodings           pprint              uuid
_testbuffer         engineio            profile             venv
_testcapi           ensurepip           pstats              warnings
_testconsole        enum                pty                 wave
_testimportmultiple errno               py_compile          weakref
_testinternalcapi   eventlet            pyasn1              webbrowser
_testmultiphase     faulthandler        pyasn1_modules      websocket
_thread             filecmp             pyclbr              werkzeug
_threading_local    fileinput           pycparser           winreg
_tkinter            flask               pydoc               winsound
_tracemalloc        flask_cors          pydoc_data          wsgiref
_uuid               flask_socketio      pyexpat             xdrlib
_warnings           fnmatch             pytz                xml
_weakref            formatter           queue               xmlrpc
_weakrefset         fractions           quopri              xxsubtype
_winapi             ftplib              random              yaml
_xxsubinterpreters  functools           re                  zipapp
_yaml               gc                  regex               zipfile
_zoneinfo           genericpath         reprlib             zipimport
abc                 getopt              requests            zlib
aifc                getpass             requests_oauthlib   zoneinfo

Enter any module name to get more help.  Or, type "modules spam" to search
for modules whose name or summary contain the string "spam".
```

However when I go to Visual Studio and try to import this package it doesn't show up. Whereas other packages I have installed "automatically" do! I would appreciate any help you can offer me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi hungti, if my answer helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) . And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this document](https://github.com/Binance-docs/Binance_Futures_python#Installation) and I can get what I want. The most importance thing is that the command does not copy the generated files into the pyhton 3.9.4 folder automatically. You have to copy them manually.

[image]

**1)** first download the project under [this link](https://github.com/Binance-docs/Binance_Futures_python#Installation) and then unpack the file.

Run these under cmd:

```
cd xxx\xxx\Binance_Futures_python-master`

C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe setup.py install
```

**After that**, copy the changed two folders `binance_d` and `binance_f` from `Binance_Futures_python-master` folder into `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages`

**Then**, close VS, restart VS and choose the right **python 3.9** as python environment. Then type the code and you will get what you want.

Comment: Solved it! I appreciate it, thank you very much!